# Loading picture show loading progress

Tags: android

I use the function to show picture:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = loadBitmap(URL);
```

loadBitmap() as below:

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
try {
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)this.fetch(url));
return bm;
}
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
}
```

And fetch() below:

```
public Object fetch(String address) {
try {
URL url = new URL(address);
Object content = url.getContent();
return content;
}
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return this;
}
```

I want to show the loading progress or a load.png while it loading.
And end with the picture loading finish and show it.
How can I do?
I try to make like ProgressDialog.
But I don't know how to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` to show a Progress Dialog on the `PreExecute()` method and hide/dismiss it in the `PostExecute()` method.

```
ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(this); // Create Progress Dialog


private class DownloadBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Display progressDialog before download starts
        prog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        prog.hide(); //Hide Progress Dialog else use dismiss() to dismiss the dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * Perform download and Bitmap conversion here
         * 
         */
        return null;
    }

}
```

And finally call the AsyncTask through,

```
DownloadBitmap dd = new DownloadBitmap();
dd.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) for this.
Check out these links:

[Tutorial 1](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43168.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that directly, as Android doesn't support GIF files. So to away with that you have to create separate image (loading image into split images) and make animation of it. At the time of loading run the animation and once Bitmap avail stop animation and set Bitmap on ImageView

Answer (score 1):

This example shows progressbar while downloading the image and later it is invisible.

```
public class ImageDownload extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        ImageView mainImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        String imageurl = "http://ipadwallpaperportal.com/wp-content/main/2011_09/purple-flower-close-up-1024x1024-wallpaper.jpg";
        ImageDownloadMessageHandler imageDownloadMessageHandler1 = new ImageDownloadMessageHandler(
                progressBar, mainImageView);
        ImageDownlaodThread imageDownlaodThread = new ImageDownlaodThread(
                imageDownloadMessageHandler1, imageurl);
        imageDownlaodThread.start();

    }

    class ImageDownlaodThread extends Thread {
        ImageDownloadMessageHandler imageDownloadMessageHandler;
        String imageUrl;

        public ImageDownlaodThread(
                ImageDownloadMessageHandler imageDownloadMessageHandler,
                String imageUrl) {
            this.imageDownloadMessageHandler = imageDownloadMessageHandler;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(imageUrl);
            Message message = imageDownloadMessageHandler.obtainMessage(1,
                    drawable);
            imageDownloadMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
            System.out.println("Message sent");
        }

    }

    class ImageDownloadMessageHandler extends Handler {
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        View imageTextView;

        public ImageDownloadMessageHandler(ProgressBar progressBar,
                View imageTextView) {
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.imageTextView = imageTextView;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(((Drawable) message.obj));
            imageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strUrl) {
        /**
         * This is one method
         */
        long x1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Drawable d = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = (InputStream) new URL(strUrl).getContent();
            d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long x2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long res = x2 - x1;
        Log.v("Image Downloading Time", "" + res);
}
```